# Leaving Bodybuilding after some years may cause bulging of the body?

Tags: bodybuilding

I have read somewhere and heard from so many friends and people that if we leave bodybuilding after certain years it might bulge or body and etc. Is it true?

Comment: What was the reasoning behind the claim? What kind of harm is being claimed?

Comment: Sorry @Dave, I have edited the question now?

Comment: @HimanshuPrasad while I know you may want a yes or no answer, the goal of Stack Exchange is to help others with the same question as well. We also require that answers are backed up, so everyone can decide for themselves whether they agree with the answer or not. This means that a simple yes or no isn't sufficient to answer the question. So please try to make your questions more elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you may be referring to is that when you build extremely large muscles, and then fail to maintain them (so they shrink back to normal), the skin around them may appear stretched. The same happens for pregnant women, or obese people who lose a lot of fat. Obviously the skin will appear stretched afterwards, and may never become as tight as it once was.

That said, you only have to worry about this phenomenon if you plan to grow your muscles to positively gigantic proportions. If you simply build your body to look strong and masculine, but not exactly like the Hulk, you won't have anything to worry about. If you do want to look like the Hulk, I fear you'll have to live with some sagging if you ever abandon your training completely.

Answer (score 3):

If by "bulging" you mean "getting fat", I think it only happens if you stop bodybuilding and neglect to adjust your diet to your new lifestyle. In this case you end up eating far too much for what your body really needs, so you can get fat because of that.

But muscles cannot "transform" to fat. They are totally different types of cells.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my current condition was caused entirely by my massively over-developed obliques. `</sarcasm>`